# Make Array set of HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting following string from API response. I have to transform this string into a set of Array. Text and following images should be one group. Text after image should create a new group with the following images. The question is how to run a loop over HTML string.

**API Response**

```
<p>aaaaa</p>
<p><img src="img.jpg" alt="" width="369" height="224" /></p>
<p><img src="img.jpg"alt="" width="369" height="224" /></p>
<p>bbbb</p>
<p>bbbb</p>
<p><img src="img.jpg" /></p>
<p>ccc</p>"
```

**Expected output:**

```js
[
  ['aaaaa', '<img src="img.jpg" alt="" width="369" height="224" />', '<img src="img.jpg"alt="" width="369" height="224" />'],
  ['bbbb', 'bbbb', '<img src="img.jpg" />'],
  ['ccc']
]
```

The function will be like

```
function makeHtmlSet(){
var htmlSet = []
 for(var i=0;i<?;i++){
   if(?.nodeType===Node.textNode){
      htmlSet = [];
      htmlSet.push(?);
   }
   else{
    htmlSet.push(?);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: If the response comes as text, you'll need a library to parse it into HTML.

Comment: Is there only ever one child node (of any type) of the parent `p` elements?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, there will be one child node ever and that will be `p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can do this with jQuery by passing the text-based HTML in to the jQuery function - with a slight caveat that you'll need to wrap it in an artificaial parent (`div` in the code below).

Then your logic is a little complex, you don't generate a new array until after an image, and two text nodes next to one another gets passed to the same array... so a little logic is required.

All in, the below seems to satisfy your needs.

```js
var input = '<p>aaaaa</p>' +
'<p><img src="img.jpg" alt="" width="369" height="224" /></p>' + 
'<p><img src="img.jpg"alt="" width="369" height="224" /></p>' + 
'<p>bbbb</p>' + 
'<p>bbbb</p>' + 
'<p><img src="img.jpg" /></p>' + 
'<p>ccc</p>';

var $input = $("<div>" + input + "</div>");
var output = [];
var hasPassedImg = true
$("p",$input).each(function(){
  var hasImg = $(this).children("img").length>0
  if(hasImg){
     current.push($(this).html());
     hasPassedImg = true;
  }
  else{
     var text = $(this).text();
     if(hasPassedImg){
         current = [];
         output.push(current);
         hasPassedImg = false;
     }
     current.push(text);
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think better way is to use  DOMParser
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Answer (score 1):

As you describe , your api return is string and your html string have `p` as a parent root . First you can remove `<p>` by regex and replace functions. You can split your string into array by `</p>` delimeter . Finally you can create new array as you want ....

Here I made for fixed string only

```js
var str = '<p>aaaaa</p>'+
'<p><img src="img.jpg" alt="" width="369" height="224" /></p>'+
'<p><img src="img.jpg"alt="" width="369" height="224" /></p>'+
'<p>bbbb</p>'+
'<p>bbbb</p>'+
'<p><img src="img.jpg" /></p>'+
'<p>ccc</p>';

function makeHtmlSet(){
  var htmlSet = [];
  var reg = /<p>/g;
  var newStr = str.replace(reg, "");
  newStr = newStr.split('</p>');
  htmlSet.push([newStr[0].trim(),newStr[1].trim(),newStr[2].trim()]);
  htmlSet.push([newStr[3].trim(),newStr[4].trim(),newStr[5].trim()]);
  htmlSet.push([newStr[6].trim()]);
  return htmlSet;
}

console.log(makeHtmlSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply You can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to `parse` the string to `DOM Document`.It have the method `parseFromString()`

> The DOMParser interface provides the ability to parse XML or HTML source code from a string into a DOM Document.
>
> > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

```js
var data='<p>aaaaa</p><p><img src="img.jpg" alt="" width="369" height="224" /></p><p><img src="img.jpg"alt=""width="369" height="224" /></p><p>bbbb</p><p>bbbb</p><p><img src="img.jpg" /></p><p>ccc</p>'

function parseData(data){
    parser=new DOMParser();
    htmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
    var ptags = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var output = [];
     var temp = [];
   
      $(ptags).each(function(index){
        if($(this).children("img").length>0){
          temp.push($(this).html());
       }
      else{
         var text = $(this).text();
         if(0==$(this).index() || $(this).prev('p').children("img").length>0){
        temp=[];
          output.push(temp);  
       }
        temp.push(text);
      }
    });
    return output;
 }
console.log(parseData(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your response is a string:
Create a hidden div:

`<p id="demo" style="display:none">Demo div.</p>`

Set the innerHTML of this div to the string:

```
el = document.getElementById("demo")
el.innerHTML = str;
```

Get the list of all p elements like so:

```
arr = el.querySelectorAll("p")

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i].firstChild.nodeName == "IMG") //do img stuff
    if(arr[i].firstChild.nodeName == "#text") //do text stuff
}
```

This should answer your question as to how to loop through HTML.

You can the remove the element:

`el.parentNode.removeChild(el);`

Comment: This won't work since the string is not it the DOM. It could work by a dirty trick such as making this string the innerHTML of some hidden div, and then running the DOM query on that div. I'd probably advise against it though (security and other issues)

Comment: The question asked how to loop through an HTML string. This is indeed a "dirty" solution, and not recommended, but hopefully, it helps the OP in a way.